# Collision Between Two Particles: Writing the Mass As A Function of The Angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, momentum, conservation-laws

> *Suppose we have two masses, $m_1$ and $m_2$, where $m_2$ is at rest, and $m_1$ is headed directly towards $m_2$. I would like to write the ratio of the masses as a function of the angle.*

Using Conservation of Energy, Conservation of Momentum, and applying the Law of Cosines to the the triangle that the initial momentum vector and final momenta vectors form, I obtain these three equations:

(1) $ m_1^2 v_1^2 = m_1^2 v_1^2~' + m_2^2 v_2^2~' - (m_1 v_1)(m_2 v_2) \cos \theta$ (Law of Cosines)

(2) $m_1 v_1^2 = m_1 v_1^2~' + m_2 v_2^2~'$ (Cons. of Energy)

(3) $m_1 \mathbf{v}_1 = m_1 \mathbf{v}_1~' + m_2 \mathbf{v}_2~' $ (Cons. of Mom.)

Taking the magnitude of the Conservation of Momentum equation, and squaring the result, yields

(4) $m_1^2 v_1^2 = m_1^2 v_1^2~' + m^2 v_2^2~' + (m_1 m_2)(v_1~' v_2~') \cos \theta$

I would like to try to eliminate the variables $v_1~'$ and $v_2~'$, seeing as in a experimental setting they might be a little more difficult to measure; however, I would like to keep the variable $v_1$, because it is a little more easy to determine--suppose the moving particle is an electron, then $m_1$ is known, and $v_1$ can be easily determine by knowing the accelerating voltage.

I was hoping that someone might guide me towards the correct path, I certainly would appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elastic collision in two dimensions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46089/)

Comment: In any case, you should note that there are two scattering angles in the problem. One often defines $\theta$ as the angle between in $\hat{v}_1$ and $\hat{v}'_1$ and $\phi$ as the angle between $\hat{v}_1$ and $\hat{v}'_2$.

Comment: Well, I was defining $\theta$ as the angle between the final velocity vectors. Would this not be helpful?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate: I am asking for advice as to how I might write $\displaystyle \frac{m_1}{m_2}$ as a function of the angle (some angle); but the other question asks to verify unrelated equations.